# How to interpret this "Initial Value Problem"?

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

I am reading the O.D.E. book by Chicone, which has the following example:

[image]

I am very confused about the part circled in red. The book is setting up the problem like this:

$$\begin{cases}
y' = (a \cot \tau + b)y - y^3 \\
\tau ' = 1\\
\tau(0, \xi) = 0\\
y(0, \xi) = \xi
\end{cases}$$
I don't understand why in the initial conditions, the functions depend on $2$ variables.

I am used to IVP's looking like this:

$$\begin{cases}
y' = (a \cot \tau + b)y - y^3 \\
\tau ' = 1\\
\tau(t_0) = \tau_0\\
y(t_0) = y_0
\end{cases}$$

and we denote the solution of this problem by something like
$$t \mapsto \phi(t, \tau_0, y_0).$$

But I really don't understand the notation used in this example. Can someone please explain the situation?

Comment: They basically are introducing a function that depends on time with the initial condition of the problem as a parameter. This is the same as what you said, except they don't introduce a $\tau_0$, it's just $0$ regardless of the value of $\xi$. If I had to venture a guess I'd say the goal is to invoke Poincare-Bendixson further down (by recasting the original problem as a 2D autonomous system).

Comment: @Ian I see, thanks. Below, they are actually doing something with a Poincare map and trying to analyze periodic orbits and stability. Now that I understand the setup, I can read and find out exactly what they're doing haha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a single IVP, but a whole family if IVPs, one for every $\xi \in \mathbb{R}$. So the second variable $\xi$ in $y(t,\xi)$ tells you which of these IVPs that the function $t \mapsto y(t,\xi)$ solves.

Comment: Oh okay so for a fixed $\xi$ the IVP is $$\begin{cases}
y' = (a \cot \tau + b)y - y^3 \\
\tau ' = 1\\
\tau(0) = 0\\
y(0) = \xi
\end{cases}$$ and they are letting $y(t, \xi)$ and $\tau(t, \xi)$ be the solution. It's a bit strange, because they are showing $\tau$ as depending on the initial condition of $y$ (which it doesn't in this case) but they are not showing $y$ as depending on the initial condition of $\tau$ .

Comment: Well, the initial condition for $\tau(t)$ is always $\tau(0)=0$, so there's no dependence to show.